# Comma removed in number-entity in LuisRecognizerResult

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I'm using MS LUIS in my bot. In one intent I'd like to recognize numbers. When the user enters numbers containing a comma such as "1,25" the LuisRecognizer recognizes "1,25" as a number. I use the RecognizeAsync method like this:

```
var luisresult = _recognizer.RecognizeAsync<MyLuisModel>(context, cancellationToken);
```

MyLuisModel was generated using LUISgen:

```
public class M<LuisModel : IRecognizerConvert {
    public enum Intent {
        AnIntent,
        ....
    }

    [JsonProperty("intents")]
    public Dictionary<Intent, IntentScore> Intents;
    
    public class _Entities
    {
        // Built-in entities
        public double[] number;
        ....
    }

    // More stuff
}
```

Now the problem is that when the number "1,25" was recognized, the entity number does not contain 1.25 as double value, but 125.

I'm from germany and we use "," as fraction delimiter.

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues/2097#issuecomment-531364880) post on github I tried setting `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` to german culture:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("de-DE");
```

to overwrite CurrentCulture which is used by double.TryParse() but without success.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer. I think I still used the LUIS V2 endpoint instead of the newer V3. I've updated my Recognizer to now look like this:

```cs
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder;
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LuisV3;

namespace MyNamespace {

    public class MyRecognizer : IRecognizer {
        private LuisRecognizer _recognizer;
        private RecognizerOptionsV3 _options;

        public MyRecognizer(string appId, string apiKey, string host) {
            _options = new LuisRecognizerOptionsV3(
                new LuisApplication(appId, apiKey,host)
            );

            _recognizer = new LuisRecognizer(_options);
        }
    }

    public virtual async Task<RecognizerResult> RecognizeAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await _recognizer.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }

    public virtual async Task<T> RecognizeAsync<T>(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) where T : IRecognizerConvert, new()
    {
        return await _recognizer.RecognizeAsync<T>(turnContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Note the usage **LuisRecognizerOptionsV3** in the constructor where I've used LuisRecognizerOptionsV2 before. Changing it to V3 was the crucial part and now "1,25" is correctly parsed into 1.25 double value.

`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` now is set to "de-DE". When using V2 it was set to `InvariantCulture`. Maybe this was kind of a bug in V2.